# Where is my database password in Altostra project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, altostra

I’ve created a project in Altostra. I've created a Lambda function in the vscode extension and connected it to an RDS instance. The password is apparently auto-generated and “accessible to any lambda”, but where do I access it?

[image]

Comment: As it says, in [*Secrets Manager*](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/)…?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect lambda to the database resource, you will have connection details provided for you into lambda's environment variable.
[image]

Here you have **DB_SECRET_RDS02**, representing the "secret" you need.
Then, in the Lambda code, you will have access to the variable through **process.env**

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk')

// retrieving host and port
const [host, port] = process.env.DB_RDS02.split(':')
// retrieving secret from SecretManager
const secretManager = new aws.SecretsManager()
const secret = await secretManager.getSecretValue({
  SecretId: process.env.DB_SECRET_RDS02
}).promise()
// retrieving data from secret
const { username, password } = JSON.parse(secret.SecretString)
```